# System.ArgumentException: "Элемент с тем же ключом уже был добавлен." Dictionary c# для System.Management

Tags: c#, словари

есть два метода для кнопок WPF

```
private void ProcessorInfo()
        {
            Dictionary<object, object> myPropertyResults = new Dictionary<object, object>();
            ManagementClass myManagementClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_Processor");
            ManagementObjectCollection myManagementCollection = myManagementClass.GetInstances();
            PropertyDataCollection myProperties = myManagementClass.Properties;
            foreach (var obj in myManagementCollection)
            {
                foreach (var myProperty in myProperties)
                {
                    bool keyExists = myPropertyResults.ContainsKey(Name);
                    if (keyExists)
                    {
                        myPropertyResults.Add(myProperty.Name,
                       obj.Properties[myProperty.Name].Value);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        myPropertyResults[Name] = obj.Properties[myProperty.Name].Value;
                    }

                }

                foreach (var myPropertyResult in myPropertyResults)
                {

                    InfoList.Items.Add(myPropertyResult.Key + ":" + myPropertyResult.Value);

                }
            }


        }
        private void NetworkInfo()
        {
            Dictionary<object, object> myPropertyResults = new Dictionary<object, object>();
            ManagementClass myManagementClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapter");
            ManagementObjectCollection myManagementCollection = myManagementClass.GetInstances();
            PropertyDataCollection myProperties = myManagementClass.Properties;
            foreach (var obj in myManagementCollection)
            {
                foreach (var myProperty in myProperties)
                {
                    bool keyExists = myPropertyResults.ContainsKey(Name);
                    if (keyExists)
                    {
                        myPropertyResults.Add(myProperty.Name,
                       obj.Properties[myProperty.Name].Value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        myPropertyResults[Name] = obj.Properties[myProperty.Name].Value;
                    }
                }

                foreach (var myPropertyResult in myPropertyResults)
                {

                    InfoList.Items.Add(myPropertyResult.Key + ":" + myPropertyResult.Value);

                }
            }
}
```

Ошибка при вызове метода NetworkInfo();

myPropertyResults.Add(myProperty.Name,
obj.Properties[myProperty.Name].Value);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пишете:

> ```
> bool keyExists = myPropertyResults.ContainsKey(Name);
> if (keyExists)
> {
>     myPropertyResults.Add(myProperty.Name,
>    obj.Properties[myProperty.Name].Value);
> }
>
> else
> {
>     myPropertyResults[Name] = obj.Properties[myProperty.Name].Value;
> }
> ```

Получается, у вас `keyExists` == `true`, когда в словаре уже есть `Name` (наверное, `myProperty.Name` должно быть написано?). И если есть, то вы пытаетесь добавить в словарь ключ `myProperty.Name`, который уже есть в словаре, и получаете `ArgumentException`. Попробуйте исправить условие на `if (keyExists == false)`. И разберитесь, что у вас такое `Name` и как оно коррелирует с `myProperty.Name`. После этого можно будет дать уточненный ответ.

Видится, что весь этот кусок кода можно заменить на:

```
myPropertyResults[myProperty.Name] = obj.Properties[myProperty.Name].Value;
```

Обращение к словарю по индексу не вызывает исключения, когда такой ключ уже есть в словаре. Если таковой уже есть, для него перезаписывается значение на новое. Если же нет – создается новый с указанным значением.